# PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist - Got this exception when run method 2nd time

Tags: java, servlets, persistence, dao

The first time I run the method, it works fine, the object is persisted. But the 2nd time it fails and give me the exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.edu.ifpb.calendario.models.Usuario
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
br.edu.ifpb.calendario.dao.GenericDAO.persist(GenericDAO.java:29)
br.edu.ifpb.calendario.servlets.CalendarioServlet.cadastrarAnotacao(CalendarioServlet.java:122)
br.edu.ifpb.calendario.servlets.CalendarioServlet.doPost(CalendarioServlet.java:76)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.edu.ifpb.calendario.models.Usuario
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:97)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:442)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:266)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
br.edu.ifpb.calendario.dao.GenericDAO.persist(GenericDAO.java:29)
br.edu.ifpb.calendario.servlets.CalendarioServlet.cadastrarAnotacao(CalendarioServlet.java:122)
br.edu.ifpb.calendario.servlets.CalendarioServlet.doPost(CalendarioServlet.java:76)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

That's my method to insert a new Note to an User:

```
public void cadastrarAnotacao(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ParseException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuario");
    AnotacaoDAO anotacaoDAO =  new AnotacaoDAO();
    Anotacao anotacao = new Anotacao();

    String mensagem = request.getParameter("mensagem");
    String dataString = request.getParameter("data");
    Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dataString);

    anotacao.setData(data);
    anotacao.setMensagem(mensagem);
    anotacao.setUsuario(usuario);
    usuario.setAnotacao(anotacao);
    anotacaoDAO.persist(anotacao);
    anotacaoDAO.close();

    session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
    response.sendRedirect("calendario.do?op=eventos");
}
```

It happens when try to execute the following line:

```
anotacaoDAO.persist(anotacao);
```

Any sugestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to persist anotacao, which has a reference to a user object, but the user object itself is not managed by your entity manager, so it has no way to point to it in the database. Try to have the user object be pulled from the db, and then to set the anotacao's user object to that.